# Swift WatchOS Wait for user input

Tags: xcode, swift, watchkit, watchos-2

```
@IBAction func switchedButton(value: Bool) {
    dump(self.showPopup("Test"))
}

func showPopup(textMessage: String) -> Bool {

    let action1 = WKAlertAction(title: "Approve", style: .Default) { () -> Void in
        return true
    }

    let action2 = WKAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { () -> Void in

        return false
    }

    presentAlertControllerWithTitle("Confirm", message: textMessage, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet, actions: [action1, action2])

    return false

}
```

This will always return false. How can I wait for the user to select Approve or Cancel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always returns false because by the time the user has tapped on an action the `showPopup` method has already returned. It essentially makes this method asynchronous.

Note that the callbacks on `WKAlertAction` specify no return value, so you cannot `return` anything from them.

What you want to do is pass a callback block to `showPopup` that you can invoke when the user interacts:

```
@IBAction func switchedButton(value: Bool) {
   self.showPopup("Test") { result in
       // result is a bool 
   }
}

// callback expects a single Bool parameter
func showPopup(textMessage: String, callback: (Bool) -> ()) {
    let action1 = WKAlertAction(title: "Approve", style: .Default) { () -> Void in
        callback(true)
    }

    let action2 = WKAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { () -> Void in
        callback(false)
    }

    presentAlertControllerWithTitle("Confirm", message: textMessage, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet, actions: [action1, action2])
}
```